# How to add INR at the end of price in the price column using bash scripting. For eg. adding INR after 10000 and making it 10000 INR

Tags: bash, unix

I have a column of price with just the price values. I need to add the type of currency after the price in the price column. For eg. adding INR after 10000 and making it 10000 INR.

```
price
12500000
20000
50000
85000
```

Desired output is :

```
price
12500000 INR
20000 INR
50000 INR
85000 INR
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{if (NR>1) $1=$1" INR";print}' file
```

Output:

```
price
12500000 INR
20000 INR
50000 INR
85000 INR
```